# Component not update after updating props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My question is why the component did not update after update the props. This is my code that explain me well:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.topWeakSlotsData = {};
        this.topWeakSlotsData['loading'] =  true;
        this._fetchWeeklyWeakSlots();
    }

    _fetchWeeklyWeakSlots() {
      var _this = this;
      fetch("...")
      .then(function(response) {
          return response.json()
      }).then(function(json) {

          _this._elaborateTopWeakSlots(json['return']);

      }).catch(function(ex) {
          console.log('parsing failed', ex)
      })
    }

    _elaborateTopWeakSlots(data) {
      ...
      this.topWeakSlotsData['options'] = {
        ...
      }

      this.topWeakSlotsData['loading'] =  false;

    }

    render() {
      return (
        <HighchartContainer data = {this.topWeakSlotsData} container ="chart1" />
      )
    }
}

export default class HighchartContainer extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
   }

   shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
     console.log("should update");
     return true;
   }

   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
     console.log(nextProps);
   }

   renderLoading() {
      return (
          <div>
           <Loader />
          </div>
      );
   }

   renderChart() {
      return (
         <div>
            <Highchart container = {this.props.container} options = {this.props.data.options}/>
         </div>
       );
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
           {this.props.data.loading ? this.renderLoading() : this.renderChart()}
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

As you can see when the fetch finish I change the `loading` from `true` to `false` and I fill also the options array, but `shouldComponentUpdate` or `componentWillReceiveProps` is not called and the component is not refreshed, what I wrong?

Comment: Could you clean up the indentation please? Right now it looks kinda messy and I can't dig through it.

Comment: @Ninetainedo I just do it, hope this is better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `App` component will only re-render the `HighChartContainer` component when either App's props or state changes.  You are currently storing `topWeakSlotsData` as a class property, so the component will not update when it changes.  You need to store it as state on `App`.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            topWeakSlotsData: {
                loading: true
            },
            lowWeakSlotsData: {
                loading: false // or whatever data you want here
            }
        }
        this._fetchWeeklyWeakSlots();
    }

    _fetchWeeklyWeakSlots() {
      var _this = this;
      fetch("...")
      .then(function(response) {
          return response.json()
      }).then(function(json) {    
          _this._elaborateTopWeakSlots(json['return']);

      }).catch(function(ex) {
          console.log('parsing failed', ex)
      })
    }

    _elaborateTopWeakSlots(data) {
        this.setState({
            topWeakSlotsData: {
               loading: false,
               options: data.options // or wherever else
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <HighchartContainer data = {this.state.topWeakSlotsData} container ="chart1" />
      )
    }
}
```

### Edit

As the other answer points out you can refactor you `_fetchWeeklyWeakSlots` method to use arrow/lambda functions, e.g.

```
_fetchWeeklyWeakSlots() {  
    fetch("...")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => json['return'])
        .then(_elaborateTopWeakSlots)
        .catch(ex => {
            console.log('parsing failed', ex)
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, can I have multiple state? for example `this.state.topWeakSlotsData` or `this.state.lowWeakSlotsData' etc, and then update for example only `this.state.topWeakSlotsData` or the other with the fetch?

Comment: Yes, when you call `setState` you just provide an object to update that part of the state, the other parts will stay the same.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please update the example adding this key `lowWeakSlotsData` at the same level of `topWeakSlotsData`?

Comment: I have see the edited code, thanks! I have another question, can I add later in the code an other key to the State at the same level of `topWeakSlotsData` and so not initiate in the constructor?

Comment: You can do it, but it can cause problems if you are passing it as a prop, and the component receiving the prop gets null when it expects an object.  For this reason it is probably best to initialise state with all keys that are going to be stored there, and just use empty objects if you don't have initial data.

Comment: Thank you so much! Have you got a good book to suggest to study react?

Comment: I haven't found any books that are consistently recommended, and many of the books from even 1-2 years ago are not up to date with current best practices.  [This Udemy course](https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-react-web-app-developer-course/) comes well recommended to me, although I have not personally taken it.

Answer (score 2):

Once your fetch promise resolves, you will need to update your state by passing your response to this.setState()

```
var _this = this

fetch(url)
    .then( function(response) { return response.json() }) // parse our response into json
    .then( function(json) { _this.setState({json: json}) } // set our state based on our parsed response
```

Once your state has been updated, you can reference {this.state.json} from within your component.

**Bonus**
If you use ES6 arrow functions: **args => { //do stuff here }** you don't need *var _this = this* because of how *this* is handled.

The above example becomes:

```
fetch(url)
    .then( response => response.json() )
    .then( json => this.setState({ json: json })
```